# make UTF-8 available For Put arabic Data in Mysql DB with Spring

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8

hey everybody i want to put arabic data with my code in the mysql database  in my webApp :

the technologies that i have used is : Spring MVC / Hibernate:

its my code in my Busines Logic part :

```
 transaction.setExplaination("Something with Arabic alphabet");
 ..
 ..
 getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(transaction);
```

when i get Explaination for my transaction and show it in .jsp page it has been shown like ??????
and its my problem .

in the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml :

at first i used it :

```
  <bean id="driverManagerDataSource"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_Name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
     <property name="username" value="root"/>
     <property name="password" value="myjava123"/>

</bean>
```

but it cause Error for my xml so i've delete it .

i have used org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
in my web.xml :

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

but also no difference in result

i will appreciate if some one Show me the Way that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you were getting in your XML was most likely due to using '&' which is not an allowed entity in XML. You should definitely encode the connection, so the work connection url should be something like

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_Name?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

You can also make sure that your server is configured properly, for tomcat for instance adding URIEncoding to connector

```
<connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

will specify the character encoding used to decode the URI. You should find an equivalent for your server